# How to modify environment variables like PATH at startup?

Tags: applications, boot, shell, processes

I'm trying to add `/data/bin` to variable `PATH` at startup in order to have it available for any other app.
In Ubuntu I use the file `/etc/environment`, I cannot find anything similar in Android.
I discovered that `adb shell` detects `/data/bin` existence and adds it to `PATH`, the system doesn't seem to do the same at boot though.

Answer (score 3):

> I discovered that `adb shell` detects `/data/bin` existence and adds it to `PATH`, the system doesn't seem to do the same at boot though.

It's because `adb shell` starts a [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) process (Android's default is [MirBSD Korn Shell](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm)) which reads its configuration file `/etc/mkshrc` and can easily change environment variables. But apps inherit their environment from `zygote`, so we need to set variables before `zygote` starts.

Edit `/init.rc` file or any other `.rc` file or create your own. Append or prepend directories to Android's default `PATH`:

```
# /system/etc/init/path.rc

on init
    export PATH /data/bin:/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin
```

---

### DETAILS:

On Linux distros `/etc/environment` is evaluated by PAM (a set of libraries called modules) which is a centralized authentication mechanism used by privilege granting and administering programs like `login`, `su`, `sshd`, `passwd`, `useradd` etc. First process `init` - after starting system services  - drops us to a login shell or display manager (which starts a display server like X.Org to show GUI), running on a virtual terminal. When logging in a user, shells and display managers are configured to read and set environment from different files like `passwd`, `login.defs`, `profile`, `bashrc` `xsessionrc` etc. usually found in `/etc` or user's `HOME` directory. This environment is inherited by CLI utilities as well as GUI programs which run in desktop environment, including terminal emulators. Applications which attach to terminals also set `TERM`.

However on Android there is no concept of `getty`, `login`, text terminal logins and traditional X window system. There are no user sessions and hence no login files. `init` starts `zygote` which loads Android's Java framework, and after starting services in `system_server`, it forks virtual machines in which apps run. So the first thing we see (after animation ends) is an app; System UI (lock screen) or Home/Launcher app hosted by SurfaceFlinger - Android's display server. Mainly environment of all these programs is set in `init`'s `.rc` files through `export` [command](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md#commands). `/init.environ.rc` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/rootdir/init.environ.rc.in))</sup> exports variables like `ANDROID_ROOT`, `ANDROID_DATA`, `ANDROID_STORAGE` and others.  Or programs set some variables themselves e.g. `logd` sets `TZ` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/logd/main.cpp#427))</sup> to ensure correct timestamps in `logcat`, and `adbd` sets `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/adb/daemon/main.cpp#196))</sup>.

Commonly used variables for Java framework are defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/os/Environment.java#33). `PATH` is set by `init` on boot <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/init/init.cpp#574))</sup> and is part of Bionic libc definitions <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/libc/include/paths.h#41))</sup>. CLI shell utilities like `su` <sup>([6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/su/su.cpp#121))</sup> and `run-as` <sup>([7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/run-as/run-as.cpp#208))</sup> also define `PATH`, `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, `USER`, `SHELL` etc. `DOWNLOAD_CACHE` is set in `/init.rc` <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/rootdir/init.rc#250))</sup> and `ANDROID_ROOT` is set by `zygote` <sup>([9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp#1082))</sup> itself.

Shell specific configuration files like `bashrc` or `mkshrc` are read only if you use `adb shell` or a terminal emulator app.

---

**FURTHER READING:**

- [[INFO] TERMINAL, SHELL & DISPLAY SERVER on LINUX, ANDROID & WINDOWS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-terminal-shell-display-server-t3756163)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file: `/system/etc/bash/bashrc` and **export** your environment variable there..

Actually, the default environment variables are predefined in the ramdisk's file: `init.environ.rc`. (You may unpack the boot.img to edit it and repack & flash it)..

You may also modify those system variables in the *bashrc* file itself..

Also check the `/system/etc/mkshrc` file..

Comment: I appended `export PATH="$PATH:/data/bin"` to `/system/etc/bash/bashrc`, reboot, no success. In `/init.environ.rc`, no sign for variable `PATH` and search for any _bin_ goes blank, not that I'm so keen for editing boot.img. Could you please give some practical example?