# How to make the kernel to also check termux bin folders

Tags: kernel, termux

How can i make android kernel to always check termux binary folder for some binaries assuming they are not found in /system/bin ? I tried copying those binaries from termux bin folder into /system/bin but they refuse to be executed. I need help please.

Comment: The kernel does not check "bin folders". The shell does. Just adjust your `$PATH` variable accordingly.

Comment: Where can I find the $PATH variable?

Comment: I am executing my scripts using Xposed edge and Xposed edge queries the variables from /system/bin or /system/xbin but most of the binaries i need are not in those 2 folders like bc command jq command and so on so I am looking for a way to make Xposed edge to check termux bin folder for binaries

Comment: See my answer to [How to modify environment variables like PATH at startup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217894/218526)