# /system/sbin in $PATH variable, but the folder doesn't exist?

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-j5

I have a Chainfire-rooted Samsung Galaxy J5 with Android 7.1. The `$PATH` variable is

```
/su/bin:/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/su/xbin:/system/xbin
```

But `/system/sbin` appears not to exist at all.

Why is this? Is it normal? Could the manual creation (and planned use) of this folder cause problems? (I run into huge ones, but not sure this was the cause.)

---

*(I probably have made several mistakes, and I will post my questions one-by-one to avoid confusion. This is the first.)*

Comment: You can put any directory on `PATH`. They don't necessarily need to exist. `init` sets the default `PATH` on boot. `/system/sbin` was [removed in Android 11](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/07c5587e56860c899eaf172abd7bbb76505e859c%5E%21/#F0). Related: [How to modify environment variables like PATH at startup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217894/218526)

Comment: Thanks. It could be only a coincidence, but I run into troubles just after having created this folder. So I wanted to be sure if this could cause it. (lot of commands, like even "ls" stopped to function: "not found"...etc.)